# Basics of InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am a GM at a H-D Dealership and just had to let our graphics designer go, and I'm in a pinch. Is there an outlet I can use personally to learn the basics of InDesign, so I can get by with using some simple graphics to use with our mailers, flyers and email blast?

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is to hire a graphic designer. Attaching four wooden legs to a plank of wood doesn't make you a carpenter, and learning the basics of InDesign doesn't make you a designer. If you're serious about your business and advertising, only a good designer can help effectively communicate your message.

Answer (score 5):

You could do some online tutorials on Lynda.com, or alternatively look at some of Adobe's support videos. There are heaps of places to learn the basics of Adobe's suite of software, it just depends on how much time you've got, and what you want to do with the software.

That said, InDesign is a very sophisticated piece of software, and even the 'basics' will take some time to learn. If you're going to be producing artwork for print and email, you're going to need to learn about things like text layout, hierarchy, colour balance and print setup, just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, InDesign is complex software and takes time and patience to learn even the "basics." If you're truly in a pinch, you are probably going to want to hire someone, even on a per-project basis, to do your flyers, marketing campaigns, and email blasts.

Comment: Hi Alyssa G, welcome to GDSE. It seems to me your answer is just a repetition of what @user5854648 already said. You can [edit] your answer to elaborate.